# Kubernetes using Docker, do we need docker CRI on all nodes including Kubernetes Master Node?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to test out Kubernetes with Docker

Do we need to install docker on all instances of Kubernetes nodes including Kubernetes Master?

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need to install docker on all instances of Kubernetes including Kubernetes Master?

In short - Yes, you need docker on all nodes, including master node since kube-system pods running in master need it.

Now, strictly speaking you could go about with other container runtime engine such as rkt and avoid docker but I guess it was not your question and you can’t alotogether avoid at least one container solution.